# .net trace listener for each switch

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, trace

Currently in my application I have many trace switch and Boolean switch. The listener is configured to log into a text file. And this works. The code snippet is as below.

```
<configuration> <system.diagnostics>
<switches>
  <add name="booleanSwitch1" value="true"/>
  <add name="booleanSwitch2" value="true"/>
  <add name="traceSwitch1" value="4"/>
  <add name="traceSwitch2" value="1"/>
</switches>
<trace autoflush="true" indentsize="2">
  <listeners>
    <add name="traceTestingListner" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="d:\Traces\traceTesting.log" traceOutputOptions="DateTime">
    </add>
  </listeners>
</trace>
```

I want each switch logs to put into different log file. How can I achieve that.

Can I add a listener for each switch and redirect that log to different log files? If so how to do this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would use multiple TraceSources, which can easily be configured with different listeners: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229547(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Idea taken from [Using more than one trace listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147643/using-more-than-one-trace-listeners)

You can configure your `TraceSource` like below using multiple trace source and having separate listener for each source

```
<configuration> <system.diagnostics>
<switches>
  <add name="booleanSwitch1" value="true"/>
  <add name="booleanSwitch2" value="true"/>
  <add name="traceSwitch1" value="4"/>
  <add name="traceSwitch2" value="1"/>
</switches>
    <sources>
      <source name="booleanSwitch1Source" switchName="booleanSwitch1" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <clear />
    <add name="traceTestingListner" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="d:\Traces\traceTesting.log" traceOutputOptions="DateTime">
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="booleanSwitch2Source" switchName="booleanSwitch2" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <clear />
    <add name="traceTestingListner1" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="d:\Traces\traceTesting1.log" traceOutputOptions="DateTime">
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

You can then define your TraceSource like

```
TraceSource bswitch1 = new TraceSource("booleanSwitch1Source");
```

Also, check the below posts

[Defining multiple TraceSources not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805154/defining-multiple-tracesources-not-running)

[How to: Use TraceSource and Filters with Trace Listeners](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228993%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thank you for your quick guide. I think this require TraceSource should be declared in code. I don't to code change as the application is already in production.

Comment: Given the example of defining the trace source in code cause I was assuming that you are logging through code behind. But, whichever way you are creating trace instance, that probably need change per your configuration.